# \VerbatimInput : adjust a long line of a .dat file

Tags: verbatim, input, texinputs

In this document, `\VerbatimInput` is calling `test_2.dat`.

`test_2.dat` contains a line too long, so that the compilation produces a pdf where that line is not entirely seen:

[image]

By using `adjustbox`, one can adjust the verbatim text:

```
 \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\linewidth}
 \begin{BVerbatim}

 text

 \end{BVerbatim}
 \end{adjustbox}
```

However, this solution is only valid when the text is directly introduced as verbatim.

I have to use `\VerbatimInput` because I need to call this `tesst_2.dat` file.

Is there a way to include `adjustbox` inside `\VerbatimInput` ?

Or any solution to shrink this `\VerbatimInput` text ?

These are the `.tex` and `test_2.dat` files:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}

 \usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{fancyvrb}
 \usepackage{color,soul}
 \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}




 \begin{document}


 \RecustomVerbatimCommand{\VerbatimInput}{VerbatimInput}%
 {fontsize=\footnotesize,
  %
  frame=lines,  % top and bottom rule only
  framesep=2em, % separation between frame and text
  rulecolor=\color{Gray},
  %
  label=\fbox{\color{Black}test.dat},
  labelposition=topline,
  %
  %commandchars=\|\(\), % escape character and argument delimiters for
                  % commands within the verbatim
  %commentchar=*        % comment character
 }

 \VerbatimInput{./test_2.dat}

 \end{document}
```

The `test_2.dat` file:

```
 #####l.253:


        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E


     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220     

 14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:


        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E


     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220     

 14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:


        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E


     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220     

 14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:


        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E


     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220     

 14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:


        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E


     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220     

    14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg 



 #l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804       68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg 



 #l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg 



 ####l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg 

 #l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg 



 #l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg 


 #####l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg 



 ####l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg 

 ####l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg 


      #l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg
```

**NEW Edit: Following @egreg's comment:**

I am using `\BVerbatimInput`, inside the `\begin{adjustbox}`, like shown below, but this generates a pdf where there is no page break, and the rest of the content of the `test_2.dat` file does not appear:

Is there a way of making the `test_2.dat` file to be shown normally: - letting the `test_2.dat` file occupy as many pdf pages as it requires- ?

[image]

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}

 \usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{adjustbox}
 \usepackage{fancyvrb}
 \usepackage{color,soul}
 \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}


 \begin{document}

 \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\linewidth}
 \RecustomVerbatimCommand{\BVerbatimInput}{BVerbatimInput}%
 {fontsize=\footnotesize,
 %
 frame=lines,  % top and bottom rule only
 framesep=2em, % separation between frame and text
 rulecolor=\color{Gray},
 %
 label=\fbox{\color{Black}test.dat},
 labelposition=topline,
  %
 %commandchars=\|\(\), % escape character and argument delimiters for
                  % commands within the verbatim
 %commentchar=*        % comment character
 }

 \BVerbatimInput{./test_2.dat}
 \end{adjustbox}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: You could use `\BVerbatimInput`, but you need to add the frame yourself.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much for your comment. I have used `\BVerbatimInput` but I am afraid it does not work (forgive me if I got it wrong, see Edit ) Could you please help me? Thank you very much

Comment: @egreg OK, I finally managed to accomplish that part of the problem, but still is not solved (see the new edit) - Thanks –

Answer (score 0):

I see no “automatic” way to do it, but you can easily play with font sizes: in your setup,

```
\fontsize{7}{9}\selectfont
```

is good.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\RecustomVerbatimCommand{\VerbatimInput}{VerbatimInput}{
  fontsize=\footnotesize % default
  %
  frame=lines,  % top and bottom rule only
  framesep=2em, % separation between frame and text
  rulecolor=\color{Gray},
  %
  label=\fbox{\color{Black}test.dat},
  labelposition=topline,
  %
  %commandchars=\|\(\), % escape character and argument delimiters for
                        % commands within the verbatim
  %commentchar=*        % comment character
 }

\begin{document}

\VerbatimInput[fontsize=\fontsize{7}{9}\selectfont]{\jobname.dat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may need to add

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
```

at the very top of the document, before `\documentclass`, if you want to exercise finer control on the font size.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possibilities, using `verbatimbox`.

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}

 \usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{fancyvrb}
 \usepackage{color,soul}
 \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}



 \begin{document}


 \RecustomVerbatimCommand{\VerbatimInput}{VerbatimInput}%
 {fontsize=\footnotesize,
  %
  frame=lines,  % top and bottom rule only
  framesep=2em, % separation between frame and text
  rulecolor=\color{Gray},
  %
  label=\fbox{\color{Black}test.dat},
  labelposition=topline,
  %
  %commandchars=\|\(\), % escape character and argument delimiters for
                  % commands within the verbatim
  %commentchar=*        % comment character
 }

% \VerbatimInput{./test_2.dat}

%\clearpage
\noindent\hrulefill\raisebox{-2pt}{\fbox{\color{Black}shifted test.dat}}\hrulefill
\verbfilenobox[\leavevmode\kern-35pt\scriptsize]{./test_2.dat}

\clearpage
\noindent\hrulefill\raisebox{-2pt}{\fbox{\color{Black}blank lines retained tiny test.dat}}\hrulefill
\verbfilenobox[\leavevmode\tiny]{./test_2.dat}

\clearpage
\noindent\hrulefill\raisebox{-2pt}{\fbox{\color{Black}tiny test.dat}}\hrulefill
\verbfilenobox[\tiny]{./test_2.dat}

\clearpage
\noindent\hrulefill\raisebox{-2pt}{\fbox{\color{Black}too wide test.dat}}\hrulefill
\verbfilenobox{./test_2.dat}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]